# CKEditor bullets and numbers formatting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ckeditor

I have CKEditor in mode inline, and one of the problems i'm having is the bullets and numbers (lists) not attached to color and/or font size.

Lock the example in this image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVkJX.png

In my config.js to define font size i have this configuration:

```
config.fontSize_defaultLabel = 'Size';
config.fontSize_sizes = '8/8px;9/9px;10/10px;11/11px;12/12px;14/14px;16/16px;18/18px;20/20px;22/22px;24/24px;26/26px;28/28px;36/36px;48/48px;72/72px;96/96px;120/120px;144/144px;168/168px;192/192px;216/216px;240/240px;264/264px;288/288px;312/312px';
config.fontSize_style = {
    element: 'span',
    attributes: {'class':'font-#(size)'},
    overrides: [ {
        element: 'span', attributes: { 'class': null }
    } ]
};
```

- Is there a way to get around this ?

Comment: If you have three separate questions you should normally ask them separately that way you will get more relevant answers to each question if someone only knows one piece and also to make it easier to search for others in the future who might have similar issues.

Comment: Thank you! I will do just that !

Comment: Please use jsfiddle.net and provide some code sample so we can view what you are dealing with.

Comment: I re- edited the question, I think being more concrete. Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

In your CKEditor's folder you have a config.js file. There you can set up your toolbar to have your sections, buttons...

A sample toolbar config:

```
config.toolbarGroups = [
    { name: 'clipboard', groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ], items: [ 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo' ] },
    { name: 'editing', groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ], items: [ 'Scayt' ] },
    { name: 'links', items: [ 'Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor' ] },
    { name: 'insert', items: [ 'Image', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'SpecialChar' ] },
    { name: 'tools', items: [ 'Maximize' ] },
    { name: 'document', groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ], items: [ 'Source' ] },
    { name: 'others', items: [ '-' ] },
    '/',
    { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ], items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Strike', '-', 'RemoveFormat' ] },
    { name: 'paragraph', groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ], items: [ 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote' ] },
    { name: 'styles', items: [ 'Styles', 'Format' ] },
    { name: 'about', items: [ 'About' ] }
];
```

If you don't want or can't edit the config file, you can create when you instantiate your editor like in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/ddan/B4yGJ/489/  (JSFiddle)

Code:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {
    toolbar : [
    { name: 'clipboard', groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ], items: [ 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo' ] },
    { name: 'editing', groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ], items: [ 'Scayt' ] },
    { name: 'links', items: [ 'Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor' ] },
    { name: 'insert', items: [ 'Image', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'SpecialChar' ] },
    { name: 'tools', items: [ 'Maximize' ] },
    { name: 'document', groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ], items: [ 'Source' ] },
    { name: 'others', items: [ '-' ] },
    '/',
    { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ], items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Strike', '-', 'RemoveFormat' ] },
    { name: 'paragraph', groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ], items: [ 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote' ] },
    { name: 'styles', items: [ 'Styles', 'Format' ] },
    { name: 'about', items: [ 'About' ] }
]
});
```

Comment: The problem is not the bullets buttons or numbers are visible, because they are. But he follow the color / size defined in the text